# HTML Email in Java

Tags: java, email, html-email

I would like to open HTML Outlook window pressing jButton. I want to be able to change font color, add pictures, have signature etc. - using mailto it is impossible.
Can anyone tell me what is the best way to do that or give some examples?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so the answear is to use Java Mail API, save email (EML) and then open it with java.awt.Desktop.open.
Thank you for your help.